# Is it possible to not generate page for specific files?

Tags: doxygen

In the C++ project I am currently working on, we have set options `SHOW_FILE=YES` (necessary for getting info about typedef, global functions, etc, from headers by generating a page for each header) and `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` (necessary because if set to NO, only headers with a `\file doxygen` command will have a page, which is not the case for many of them).

The problem is that in this configuration, empty pages are generated for many kinds of files that should not have one, notably .md or .txt files into which we write a lot of documentation about various topics. These pages are unneeded (and empty) but are still visible as results in the search area depending of what the user types in it.

Is there some way to avoid generating pages for specific files (and just specifically that, we do not want to ignore those files altogether since they actually contain documentation)?

Obviously, it should be possible to obtain the desired result by turning `EXTRACT_ALL=NO` and adding a `\file` command in every header for which we want a page, but we have a high number of said headers and I wondered if there is a simpler solution.

Doxygen version is 1.9.8.
Result of command `doxygen -x Doxyfile`:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = [...]
PROJECT_NUMBER         = [...]
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = YES    
ALIASES                = [...]
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= NO
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = cpp \
                         NOT_WRAPPING
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
LAYOUT_FILE            = Layout.xml
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOC_ENUM_VAL = YES    
WARN_LOGFILE           = /DoxygenWarnings.log
INPUT_ENCODING         =
FILE_PATTERNS          = [...]
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = [...]
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = [...]
EXAMPLE_PATH           = [...]
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =
IMAGE_PATH             = [...]
INPUT_FILTER           = "sed.exe -f /InputFilter.sed"
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = NO
IGNORE_PREFIX          = [...]
HTML_OUTPUT            =
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
FULL_SIDEBAR           = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 1
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = [...]
```

Typical examples of files that gets an empty page are ones named `<xxx>Overview.txt` that we place in each folder, in order to define Doxygen groups and give description of the topic/feature corresponding to the folder.

The typical contents of such files looks like:

```
/**
 * Feature Title
 *
 * @defgroup FeatureGroupName Feature
 *
 * Here is a description of what does the feature! 
 *
 * 
 */
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? can you show the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the message to include the answers to above questions.

Comment: Can you give an example of a file that shows the problems you observe?

Comment: I edited my first message again.

Comment: You say you don't want to add a `\file` command to each header because there's many of them. Your `INPUT_FILTER` tells me you know about `sed`. You might be able to work around your problem by bulk adding `\file` to each header using `sed` and related tools (like `find` and `grep` ).